# What is the likelihood there was only one demoniac in Matthew 8:28-34 vs. two?

Tags: greek

I have read two other posts with this question, however have found the answers to simply be "it might have been..." What I would like to explore further is the possibility of there only being one demoniac in Matthew 8:28-35 and not actually two separate men.

Is it likely the language used by Matthew is indicating that the one man was "like two men" because of the fierceness and strength of the demoniac? Verse 29 also says "And behold, they cried out, "What have you to do with us, O Son of God?" (ESV). Matthew never mentions the name  "Legion" as do Mark and Luke, but perhaps this is what he meant by "two demon possessed men" (v. 28)? The word "them" in the Matthew account could refer to the "many". Does anyone have any insight on the cultural, Greek, or literary style of how Matthew wrote this?

I guess what I'm asking is for more depth in an answer, not simply "there were two men in Matthew and one wasn't focused on in Mark and Luke." This answer falls a bit short from an apologetic standpoint.

Comment: Welcome to Biblical Hermeneutics! and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and [how it is different than others](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/653/how-can-we-educate-new-users-about-our-site-distinctives/803#803). I also recommend going through the [Help Center's](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/help) sections on both asking and answering questions.

Comment: One narrative has concentrated on a single man. The other has included two. The evangelists have different contents in order to highlight different aspects of Jesus of Nazareth, whom he was and what he was to do. The question, as you state, has already been dealt with and this explanation has already been offered in the archives of the site.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there an obvious reason why we read of two demoniacs in Matt. 8:28-29 but only one is Mk. 5:2-3?](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/68819/is-there-an-obvious-reason-why-we-read-of-two-demoniacs-in-matt-828-29-but-onl)